# how to build a bar chart with multidimensional data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to build a bar chart showing comparison of cost in combination with two variables.
Data:
[image]

Cost should be in Y' axis and Age and Gender should be in X' axis.
To findout, which combination of **Age and gender** having more cost?

Can anyone help out on this ?

I tried:

```
x = c(q4$Age,q4$Gender)
y = q4$Cost
plt <- ggplot(data = q4, mapping = aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I want help on to build Age and Gender bars should be in side by side to compare the cost of each combination of Age and Gender.

Thanks a lot for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the use of `interaction` into your aes:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = interaction(age,gender), y = cost, fill = interaction(age, gender)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also create a new column in your dataframe (here using the function `mutate` from `dplyr`) and plot according to this column:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Age_Gender = paste0("Age: ",age,"\n","Gender: ",gender)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Age_Gender, y = cost, fill = Age_Gender))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust =1))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

**Data**

```r
structure(list(age = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), gender = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    cost = c(100, 45, 50, 56, 60, 55, 50, 70, 70, 60)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, which I too learned from. Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: Thanks ! glad my answer was useful for you.

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot you all.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier with a sample of your data. Please, use `dput` and check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) how to make a great R reproducible example.

However, as I read your request, you can use `tidyverse`

I wrote the following, please try this on your data inserting your relevant covariates

```
#Data
attatch(mtcars)
w <- mtcars

#Script
library(tidyverse)
w %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(cyl=as.character(cyl),
         vs =as.factor(vs)) %>% 
  bind_rows(., mutate(., cyl="all")) %>% 
  count(cyl, vs) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, n, color = vs, fill= vs))  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#fcebeb", "#edf1f9"), name="", label=c("Text 1", "Text 2")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "#1C73C2"), name="", label=c("Text 1", "Text 2"))  + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", padding = 0.1))
```

Which yields

[image]

Comment: Thankful to each one.

Answer (score 0):

```
datax$Gender <- as.factor(datax$Gender)
ggplot(datax, aes(fill=Gender, y=cost, x=Age)) + geom_bar(position="dodge", 
stat="identity")
```